# Delphi ListView style with Horizontal Separator Lines

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm doing a mobile application with Delphi Seattle 10, and emerged me a doubt in the style of the ListView.

When a Listview is empty, it looks like this,without filling all horizontal separators lines, like this :

[image]

and I wonder if its possible, I dont know, changing the style in some way so that it could look like this:

[image]

It's posible?

Answer (score 1):

Each seperator line will be added when you add a new TListViewItem. If you really want to make this, you can do it only one way. That is:

Creating a **TListViewItem**

```
var 
 aItem: TListViewItem;
```

Adding an action to your **TForm** which including **TListView** like **onCreate**

```
for I:= 0 to 10 do
begin
 aItem := TListView1.Items.Add;
 aItem.Text := '';
end;
```

This is just a little trick. Or maybe you should try to use Canvas but I don't suggest you to use Canvas for this.